# passing FormCollection to controller via JQuery Post method and getting data back...

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, parameters, postback

I am having a slight issue sending formCollection data to my controller action method in MVC using jQuery .Post method.  While I am sending the data via jQuery, it is not in the formCollection parameter of my action controller, well let me be more specific, it is in there, but not quite how I expected it to be in there...  First off, the formCollection parameter now has 2 entries... the PopID passed in (21) plus the serialized data passed in (FirstName=Fifo&LastName=Caputo&DateOfBirth=&DateOfBirth=7%2F29%2F2011+12%3A00%3A00+AM&City=&State=&Country=&Postal+Code=&deathIndicator=&email=&gender=&language=&NextOfKin=&Phone=)
What am I doing wrong here?  Controller Action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchByDemographic(int PopID, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
    }
```

JavaScript-Jquery method to pass in values...

```
    $(function () {
    $("#DemoGraphSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $("#DemoGraphID");
        var srlzdform = form.serialize();
        var PopID = <% =PopID %>
        var options = [];
        var serializedForm = form.serialize();
        $.post("/PatientACO/SearchByDemographic", {PopID:PopID,srlzdform:srlzdform}, function (data) {
            options = $.map(data, function (item, i) {
                return "<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#PatientListToAdd").html(options.join(""));
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas?  I am going to keep looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.post("/PatientACO/SearchByDemographic", srlzdform, function (data) {
```

Although I am not sure why you want to use a FormCollection instead of a viewmodel.

Perhaps you want to take a look at [NerdDinner](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/nerddinner)

So here is your view (obviously more complex than this)

```
@model TestModel

<form action="@Url.Action("SearchByDemographic","PatientACO")" method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PopID)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Text)
</form>
```

Here is your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchByDemographic(TestModel model)
{
}
```

And here is your model

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int PopID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    // more properties
}
```

This way if you store your PopID in the model you don't have to do <%: PopID %> in your javascript.

Comment: What is that doing?  How is that different from what I have?  What is a viewModel and why would I use that instead of a formCollection?  I am collecting data from a user in the form...  And note, my popID is the first parameter in my action control
How would I handle the incoming data in my controller btw?