# How to access my formcollection in action method ASP.NET mvc ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have form collection accessed in action method ,but how to get the value of it .I tried like this

```
string value = collection[1];
```

but I am not getting the value .How can I access the value in action method.

Comment: michael, could you please mark my answer as correct, i don't like to have 66 reputation :)

Comment: Focus more on helping people and less on recognition and you'll be fine....

Answer (score 33):

If you have:

```
<input type="text" name="inputName" />
```

You could use the attribute name of the element like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult yourAction(FormCollection collection)
{
     string value = Convert.ToString(collection["inputName"]);
     ...
     return View();
}
```

Comment: Works for me and is exactly same question I would have asked.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should attempt to stear clear of the formcollection object if you are able to, in favour of a strongly typed viewmodel. there are a few examples here on SO and i've linked the 1st one that I searched for:

[passing FormCollection to controller via JQuery Post method and getting data back...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877801/passing-formcollection-to-controller-via-jquery-post-method-and-getting-data-back)

however, if you're keen to tie yourself in knots :), then here's an example iterating thro a formcollection:

http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/iterate-through-system-web-mvc-formcollection/

Comment: If the Form is known - you cannot create a model. YOu need to iterate through the collection to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

Something like (code not tested) -

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddNewLink(FormCollection collection)
{
    string url = collection[1].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a view like this

```
<form action="/myController/myAction" method="post">
User Name <input type="text" name="userName" /> <br>
Country <input type="text" name="country" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Create action like below

```
public ActionResult myAction(string userName, string country){
      //do some thing with userName
      //asp.net mvc3 has automatically bind that for you
}
```

**Note: Above written code is not a recommended way of doing things, its just for a demo.**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example,hope it will help ...

```
 public class UserName
    {        
       public string FName { get; set; }
       public string LName{ get; set; }               
    }


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult FormCollectionEg()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FormCollectionEg(FormCollection data)
        {
            UserName UserObj = new UserName();
            UserObj.FName = data["fname_name"];
            UserObj.LName = data["lname_name"];
            return  RedirectToAction("DisplayFormCollectionData", UserObj);           
        }


        public ActionResult DisplayFormCollectionData(UserName reg)
        {
             return View(reg);
        }
```

Create two view -
DisplayFormCollectionData
FormCollectionEg

***DisplayFormCollectionData***

```
@model YourProjectNamespace.Models.UserName

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DisplayFormCollectionData</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h4>User Deatails</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FName)*@
                First Name....
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FName)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LName)*@
                Last Name...
            </dt>

            <dd>

                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LName)
            </dd>

        </dl>
    </div>
    <p>
        @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")*@
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

***FormCollectionEg-***

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>FormCollectionEg</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("FormCollectionEg", "Home"))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter First Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fname_id" name="fname_name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Last Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="lname_id" name="lname_name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>



    }

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred option is to use [UpdateModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx).

Instead of manually mapping the fields, this MVC method will automatically bind the properties from the data available in the request, the same way as if you had passed a strict type in as a parameter to the action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FormCollectionEg()
{
    var model = new Username();

    UpdateModel<Username>(model);

    return View(model);
}
```

The above code will include data from the QueryString aswell as the form data which may not be suitable. If you were using a parameter in the action, you'd restrict this by using [FromBody], but with UpdateModel you can still achieve the same thing by passing in the FormCollection as the value provider.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FormCollectionEg(FormCollection collection)
{
    var model = new Username();

    UpdateModel<Username>(model, collection);

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See your HTML file (or use Inspect Element) to see the name attribute in the input field. 
For instance if you have

```
<input type = "text" name = "YourName"/>
```

In the controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(FormCollection fc)     /*Using FormCollection*/
        {
                string variable_name = fc["YourName"];
                return View();
        }
```

FormCollection is one way of retrieving view data in controller. Depending on the type of value in input, you can parse its non-string value to string in the Action method.