# MVC 4 \ form submit button not working when view is using master layout

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

ok, [after long investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173580/mvc-4-form-submit-button-doesnt-do-anything) , it seems like when I have a view that was created to work with the _layout.cshtml - the submit button in the form I have doesn't work (no action is returned to controller).

Only when I created a view and unchecked "Use a layout or master page" - the button has worked!

This seems extremely unclear, so - how can I have both view with the general _layout.cshtml alongside with a [working form button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173580/mvc-4-form-submit-button-doesnt-do-anything)?

below:
Try to implement a form in MVC4 (+Razor)

**Controller (that should get the post action):**

```
public class GeneralController {
        [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult SearchResults(SearchParamsModel searchParams)
                {
                    // doin some stuff here
                    return View("SearchResultsView");
                }
}
```

**View (.cshtml)**

```
    @model Models.SearchParamsModel 
     @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResults", "General", FormMethod.Post))
             {
 <section class="form-field">
                            <input type="text" name="Property1" id="Property1" class="field field139 autocomplete-init-no-img" />
                            <label for="Property1">value1</label>
                <form action="" method="post" class="clearfix">           
                    <input 
                        type="submit" 
                        value="some value" 
                        class="submit btn blue-btn special-submit" />
                </form>
         </section>
        }
```

**Model**

```
public class SearchParamsModel 
    {
        public string Property1{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Put your code to see what is wrong

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should remove your inner form tag,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResults", "General", FormMethod.Post))
```

will generate a form tag for you.

Also, you should use the html helpers to generate your form elements:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property1)
```

Could be a possible model binding issue due to this.
The submit button belongs to your nested inner form, there is no model that is being submitted here.

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.SearchParamsModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResults", "General", FormMethod.Post))
   <section class="form-field">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property1)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property1)
      <input type="submit" value="some value" class="submit btn blue-btn special-submit" />
   </section>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did exactly what you suggested and it works! so, no need to declare on form

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem, but not the same problem you described above, resolved this way:

My "MVC 4 Layout Page" had "form" tag inside layout document. On the other side my View was connected to layout page (View page also had "using (Html.BeginForm()){...}")

So, removing "form" tag from layout page should do the thing, "because using (Html.BeginForm()){...}")" from view page is not nested any more.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the submit button in a nested `Form` and the input `Property1` is not a descendant of that form.  Move the input element into the nested form or remove the nested form altogether

Edit: your nested form element also doesn't specify the action, so if `General/SearchResults` is not the default for this view, you won't get your expected results